# Open document with startActivity(intent) - wrong document opened

Tags: android, android-intent

When opening a document with the Office app (both Word, Excel) in Android by calling `startActivity(intent)`, Office for Android displays the previously shown document whereas Google doc shows the correct document.

How can I solve this issue?

The documents are created by Word 2016 and Excel 2016 (Windows) and can be opened from Google Drive without any error. I set 
`intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");` and `intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");` in my code.

Following are code in test.

```
private class AsyncXlsLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    private File tempFile;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result == 0) {
            try {
                Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mydomain.fileprovider", tempFile);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), " No data!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Downloading " + xlsfile + "...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        Integer result = new Integer(0);
        URL u;
        xlsDir = getContext().getFilesDir();
        try{
            u = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            // Read the stream
            tempFile = new File(xlsDir + "/xlsxfiles/", tempXlsName);
            DeleteFile(tempFile, tempXlsName);
            if (tempFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
                tempFile.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            InputStream is = u.openStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                fos.write(b,0, length);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            is.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            return 0;
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException nameOfTheException){
            u = null;
            return -1;
        }
        catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
} // End AsyncXlsLoader
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Documents are created by Word 2016 and Excel 2016 (Windows) and can be opened from Google Drive without any error.  I set intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel"); and intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword"); in my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your comment into your question. You can do this yourself, by using the "edit" link below your post. When asking questions here, it's best if you include a [mcve] in your post. In this particular case, you _might_ also find relevant information in the LogCat - if so, include the relevant part of the LogCat. Good luck!